# Hive equivalent of Pig's PigRunner?

Tags: java, hive, apache-pig

Is there a Hive equivalent to Pig's [PigRunner](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/PigRunner.html) class that makes it easy to run HQL scripts from within a Java program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Spring for Apache Hadoop` framework has a `Hive` integration, having a look at
the [source code](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-hadoop/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/hadoop/hive) might give you some idea how to run hql scripts from code.

On the other hand you can also check the `Hive` sources as well (especially [CliSessionState](http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.9.0/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/hive/cli/CliSessionState.html) and [CliDriver](http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.9.0/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/hive/cli/CliDriver.html))
to see how *Hive shell* picks up a hql file (i.e: `hive -f file.q`) .

Based on these such a raw implementation can do the job:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState;

public class RunHQLScript {

    private static class MyCliSessionState extends CliSessionState {
        public MyCliSessionState(HiveConf conf, String host, int port) {
            super(conf);
            this.host = host;
            this.port = port;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        LogUtils.initHiveLog4j();
        CliSessionState ss = new MyCliSessionState(new HiveConf(SessionState.class),
                "localhost", 10000);

        ss.in = System.in;
        ss.out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
        ss.err = new PrintStream(System.err, true, "UTF-8");
        ss.fileName = "file.q";  //HQL file

        SessionState.start(ss);
        ss.connect();
        CliDriver cli = new CliDriver();
        int processFile = cli.processFile(ss.fileName);
        System.out.println("return code: " +processFile);
        ss.close();
    }
}
```

Note that a running `Thrift service` (on port 10000 by default) is needed to be able to execute the script.